# How to return the error from a promise to a redux saga catch block? Now get the error undefined

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I'm calling a firebase function in my saga. The function works properly and if an error returns, it comes to the saga's catch block. But the error variable is not passed. Here's the code:

```
const firebaseAuth = ({ email, password }) =>
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch((error) => { throw error; });


function* loginUser(action) {
  try {
    const user = yield call(firebaseAuth, action.payload);

    yield put({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { user } });
  } catch (error) {
    /* eslint-disable no-debugger */
    debugger;

    // I need to see the error here.

    yield put({ type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL });
  }
}

function* sessionSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(USER_LOGGING_IN, loginUser);
}

export default sessionSaga;
```

Currently, when the program breaks at the `debugger` statement, the error is undefined. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried putting debugger into the promise catch function? `.catch((error) => { debugger; throw error; });` ... Is the error variable undefined there as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ι think you should add your function that calling the Promise inside your try-catch block:

```
function* loginUser(action) {
  try {
      const firebaseAuth = ({ email, password }) =>
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch((error) => { throw error; });

     const user = yield call(firebaseAuth, action.payload);

    yield put({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { user } });
  } catch (error) {
    /* eslint-disable no-debugger */
    debugger;

    // I need to see the error here.

    yield put({ type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL });
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to help. The `catch` method is asynchronous and so defining the callback inside `try/catch` will imo have no effect.